# MySql Trigger Before Insert Update With Count

Tags: mysql, sql-update, insert-update, triggers

I am working for an affiliate system. I have 2 mysql tables. If table refs [known as refer table] has 5 entry with same referral id then the referrer will update+1 level.

table refs. /* refering table*/

```
id  |   u_id    |   ref_id
1   |   123     |   120
2   |   124     |   110
3   |   125     |   111
4   |   126     |   121
5   |   127     |   123
```

table ref_lev /* refering level */

```
id  |   u_id    |   ref_level
1   |   110     |   2
2   |   111     |   1
3   |   112     |   2
4   |   113     |   1
5   |   114     |   1
```

My Attempt Was

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
TRIGGER `OnrefsInsert` AFTER INSERT ON `refs` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE ref_lev 
    SET lev = lev + 1 
    WHERE u_id = OLD.u_id
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `refs` WHERE ref_id = OLD.u_id ) = 5
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You need to ask a question. If you what you tried didn't work, you need to tell us why/how. That usually implies providing an error message.

Comment: But if you had read the error message and then the documentation for `UPDATE`, you would already have found your error. Hint: `()`.

Comment: Error MSG: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `refs` WHERE ref_id = NEW.u_id = 5 END' at line 8`

Comment: So what does the manual say the syntax of `UPDATE` is?

Comment: So, what does it say now?

Comment: `UPDATE ref_lev SET lev = lev +1 WHERE u_id = 100 AND refered_total = 5`

Answer (score 0):

In your posted code the below part in `WHERE` condition is totally wrong and causing error.

```
AND SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `refs` WHERE ref_id = OLD.u_id = 5
```

I don't think you really need a trigger for this. If your main purpose is to 
update the table then you can do something like below

```
UPDATE ref_lev a 
    JOIN refs b ON a.u_id = b.u_id
    AND b.ref_id = 5 
SET a.ref_level = a.ref_level + 1
```

**EDIT:**

per comment, you can try this then

```
UPDATE ref_lev a 
JOIN 
(
 SELECT u_id,COUNT(ref_id) as countref FROM `refs` 
 GROUP BY u_id
 HAVING countref = 5
) X ON a.u_id = X.u_id
SET a.ref_level = a.ref_level + 1
```

Comment: Not quite, he's looking to increment when the count of matching rows reaches 5.

Comment: Sorry My Condition Was `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM refs WHERE ref_id = OLD.u_id ) = 5`

Comment: I have made this query: ** CREATE
  TRIGGER `OnrefsInsert` AFTER INSERT ON `refs` 
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

 UPDATE ref_lev a 
 JOIN 
 (
  SELECT u_id, COUNT(ref_id) as countref FROM `refs` 
  GROUP BY u_id
  HAVING countref = 5
 ) X ON a.u_id = X.u_id
 SET a.ref_level = a.ref_level + 1;

  END;**

But it is not working.

Comment: @Fujael, NO, Just run the `UPDATE` query as in my answer. Not within trigger. You don't need a trigger and that's what I am trying to convey.

Comment: Sorry, I need trigger because it will work back-end of my system.

Comment: @Fujael, OK. What you mean by it's not working? do you get error? post the error as well then.

Comment: I have not get any error msg but I think the result(from JOIN query) != 5 when refereed total is 5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56802/discussion-between-fujael-and-rahul).